# How do I replace insulation in an electric stove that has been soiled by mice and smells when the oven is on?

Tags: stove

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace oven insulation that has been soiled by mice and smells bad?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3767/how-do-i-replace-oven-insulation-that-has-been-soiled-by-mice-and-smells-bad)

How do I replace insulation in an electric stove that has been soiled by mice and smells when the oven is on?